# How to make old custom Magento theme Responsive after upgrading to Magento 1.9?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, themes, magento-1.9

I'm relatively new to stackoverflow and even newer to Magento. I'm facing a problem and I really hope someone here could suggest something that could help me.

I had a custom theme in Magento 1.6, and I was successfully able to upgrade to Magento 1.9, having the same theme. Now the problem is that I also want to have the old theme to be a responsive one. I don't want to buy a new responsive theme or use the magic liquidizer plugin. I have basic knowledge of PHP, HTML, CSS and jQuery, as much as one could learn from w3schools. I've tried using bootstrap but failed. It does become sort of fluid, i.e. when I re-size the browser, the slider and the images change their size and position one over other, but the main menu looks the same, it just compresses and doesn't change to the dropdown type as in a truly responsive theme. Moreover, when I open the link in my mobile, it doesn't feel responsive only zoomed out by the android/chrome browser for mobile.

I'm lost and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody guide me in the right direction? Is there any tutorial on how to make an old theme responsive in magento 1.9?

Answer (score 1):

It's still a lot of work, but much less than it used to be. In Magento 1.9 they released a new responsive theme.  It dramatically reduces the barrier to entry to make responsive themes.  It's located in the `skin/frontend/rwd/` directory. Here's a link to the [Magento CE 1.9 and EE 1.14 Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide)... that should explain a lot more.

Comment: Thank you. I, at last implemented the old theme into the same rwd responsive theme that you have mentioned. Now, the design looks mostly like the old theme and is also responsive. It still however required a lot of work and a lo of tweaking; but right now this is the only option that seems to work. I width there was another quick and easy method. Thanks anyway.